# Remove decimals from configurable option price update script

Tags: price, currency

I changed `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php` to not use decimals.
This works good for me besides the price update for configurable options.
If I choose option I still get 123.00 but I want it to be 123.

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

in file js/varien/product.js about line 773:

change this:

```
formatPrice: function(price) {
            return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
        }
```

to this:

```
formatPrice: function(price) {
        this.priceFormat.requiredPrecision = 0;
        return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
    }
```